# Prove group of order 6 is cyclic or not abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The full question is:

> Let $G$ be any group of order 6, and suppose that $a, b \in G $ with $a$ of order 3 and $b$ of order 2. Show that either G is cyclic or $ab\neq ba$.

I'm mostly confused about the formulation of the question. Does it simply want me to show that if $G$ is cyclic, then $ab = ba$? But this is true for any $x, y \in G$ since every cyclic group is abelian. So where does the assumption that $a$ is order 3 and $b$ is order 2 need to be used?

It seems to me that the implication I mentioned before is enough to show that it is never true that both $G$ is cyclic and $ab \neq ba$.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the question. You need to show that *either* $G$ is cyclic or else $ab \ne ba$. That is, assume that $G$ is not cyclic and then show that $ab \ne ba$. Alternatively, show that if $ab = ba$, then $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: So could the question be rephrased as: Show that $G$ is cyclic if and only if $ab=ba$?

Comment: It could in this case. But it's worth pointing out that "either A or B" is not the same, formally, as "A if and only if not B". The reason the two formulations are the same in this case is that, as you point out, $G$ cyclic implies $G$ abelian implies $ab = ba$.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried to write out the truth tables of $A \oplus B$ and $A \leftrightarrow \neg B$. And they seem to be the same. Also, thank you for your help!

Comment: The easiest way might be to prove "if $G$ is abelian of order $6$, then $G$ is cyclic."  Then you have that it's either cyclic or not abelian.

Comment: By the way, just so you have an idea of where things are going, you will eventually learn that the only groups of order $6$ are $\mathbb{Z}_6$ (the cyclic group of order $6$) or $S_3$ (the symmetric group on $3$ letters).

Answer (score 1):

The statement of your problem says :

> show that "either $G$ is cyclic or $ab \ne ba$".

You can take benefit of the equivalence between $\lnot p \lor q$ and $p \rightarrow q$.

In order to apply it to your problem, rephrase the statement as follows :

> "$\lnot ab = ba \lor G$ is cyclic".

Reading it in this way, your problem is simply :

> show that "if $ab = ba$, then $G$ is cyclic"

as already said by @rogerl in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $ab\neq ba$ obviously isn't cyclic, so suppose $ab=ba$. Then the order of $ab$ is 6, because:
$$(ab)^2=a^2b^2=a^2\ne e,$$
$$(ab)^3=a^3b^3=b\ne e,$$
$$(ab)^4=a^4b^4=a\ne e,$$
$$(ab)^5=a^5b^5=a^2b\ne e,$$
$$(ab)^6=a^6b^6=e.$$
(why all the $\ne e$?)